# Is there a way to make an img tag not selectable in a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an image in my page and I don't want it to pick up mouse clicks (as in the browsers inherent drag and drop or the drag select where it highlights the image in the browser.)

Is there something I can do to the img or its parent dom element or the page to make the browser not do anything when I click on the image? I need to use the mousedown for something else, but the browser seems to perform my mousedown event as well as do its own dragging or highlighting, and I don't want it to.
Any ideas?

Comment: If you're trying to do this to prevent people from copy and pasting an image or saving it, then don't expect it to be very effective on anyone who knows anything about computers.

Comment: If you're locking the door to your house, don't expect it to be very effective on anyone who knows anything about burglary...

By making things harder, you stop most people from doing something. But after that, it gets more and more difficult to stop it.

Comment: I was a hacker long before they changed the meaning of the word hacker to mean what it means today. I know better than to try and keep people from doing what they want with data on their machine. :-)

Comment: Locking all the doors and windows to your house serves as a good deterrent 99.9% of the time. Placing a locked door in front of an open gazebo is pointless. While very few people are master locksmiths, pretty much most teenagers these day know how to take a screen shot/disable js/left-click and press the context menu button/view source/open their temporary internet folder/install DownloadThemAll/or any one of the million other ways to defeat any kind of web image "DRM" you can throw at them.

Comment: http://www.plagiarismtoday.com/2008/02/26/5-reasons-to-avoid-using-drm-on-your-site/ (BTW - this article also links to some resources that provide click-preventing functionality, if you really want to ignore the advice and do it anyway)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a div the same size as the image, and then set the image to be the background of the div.

Comment: I like simple, this sounds great, but I'm trying it and it's no going. I'm making these img/divs dynamically and whenever I try to set the style="background: url(blah)" I get an error trying to set when only a getter available. And if I use style.backgroundImage = url then I get no error, but the image doesn't show.
Is there some z index or coloring I have to set in my newly created element or some inline style or something?

Comment: oh heh, new problem. I need to stretch the background image, from what  I'm reading, it's not possible. Did I miss some trick?

Comment: I ended up doing something simpler if a little goofier.
I made a div sandwich. div1 has zindex 1 and all the images are children of div1, div2 is absolute position sized and positioned over div2 with zindex 10.

Answer (score 2):

As recursive said, use a div, and set it's background image to the image you want, e.g.:

```
<div style="width: 879px; height: 576px; background-image: url(image.png);">
```

Answer (score 1):

using jquery,

```
$('img').click(function() {
  return false;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Images are [draggable by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#The_Draggable_Attribute).  To override the browser default behaviour, try:

```
<img draggable="false"...
```

Answer (score 0):

Best idea what I get, is to cover `<img ...` by some transparent `<div` and bind mousedown action to its :) EDIT: or of course, if u won't play with img, u can use it as a `background` for your div.

Comment: what do you mean "if you won't play with img" I created the image I can do whatever I want, but I don't want to make two elements if I don't have to.

Comment: I meant, if ur img is as background-image, will be harder change it, resize, etc...